# Strange colors on screen

Tags: macbook-pro, screen

Can someone please help me solve ?  The screen suddenly turned blank with strange colors on the left, as the picture shows.[image]

Comment: Looks like physical damage to me - banged halfway down the left edge, where the semi-circle is, damage spread across the two bright arcs.

Answer (score 1):

Like Tetsujin commented this is physical damage to the screen. Looks like the computer was dropped or something was dropped on it midway down on the left edge.

That is likely not covered under warranty but you should be able to attach another display to the computer and still use it until you can either take it to Apple for repairs or a third party that replaces screens on MacBooks.

You can start at an Apple store, they will at least be able to verify what exactly happened and quote you a repair price.